# Request Compression SOAP API

Tags: soap-api, soap

Does SOAP API support API request or response similar to how REST does using [compression headers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_rest_compression.htm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does.
If a client compress the request and includes a `Content-Encoding` HTTP header with the name of the compression algorithm (either gzip or deflate), Salesforce decompresses it before processing. Moreoever if the client includes a `Accept-Encoding` HTTP header (either gzip or deflate), Salesforce should compresses the response.

It's stated in the [Implementation Considerations page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/implementation_considerations.htm#sforce_api_other_compression). Here are some relevant part:

> Compression is not used unless the client specifically indicates that it supports compression. [...]
> To indicate that the client supports compression, you should include the HTTP header “Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate” or a similar heading. The API compresses the response if the client properly specifies this header. [...]
> The API supports deflate and gzip compression according to the HTTP 1.1 specification. [...]
> The API is not required to compress the response even if you have specified Accept-Encoding, but it normally does. If the API compresses the response, it also specifies a Content-Encoding header with the name of the compression algorithm used, either gzip or deflate.